# Adding "Title" column again to SharePoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, content-type, column

One of my user accidentally deleted "Title" column from a list. This list contains huge amount of data because of which we cannot recreate it. When I tried adding a new field with name "Title" sharepoint is changing the field name  to "Title0". I need to retain the same name because it is being used in some custom developed components.

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to "accidently" delete that field. There is no "delete" option available for the title field.  It's a member of each OOTB content type, and you only have the option to "hide" it, and you have to do this from the content type settings (not the list item based on the content type).

Go to List Settings

Scroll down to content types and click the document type listed there

Highlight the title field and make sure it's not set to "hidden".

Comment: Thank you Jesus, I am not sure what happend my list is not content type enabled. I will try your suggestion. Thanks again